What kind of algebraic structure is a ratio scale?
In a seminal paper, Stevens (1946) introduced a fourfold classification of scales: nominal, ordinal, interval, and ratio. He based this classification on the types of comparisons the scale preserves under transformations, namely: equality, order, differences, and ratios, respectively.
In the original paper, Stevens had linked these to algebraic groups (permutation, isotonic, linear, and similarity, respectively). However, I thought that another (perhaps more intuitive) way to describe scales could be in terms of some well-known structures:

Nominal: Equivalence relations
Ordinal: Total orders
Interval: Lebesque measures (of dimension 1)/Lawvere metric spaces
Ratio: ?

Anyone know of a structure that would describe ratio scales well? Thanks!

Maybe it's just me, but the three structures you have given seem much less intuitive than what Stevens used.

@PeterFlom Fair. I think that one advantage is that, by e.g. relating nominal scales to equivalence relations, you can specify a set of properties that the scale needs to have (reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity, https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/equivalence+relation). Same goes for total orders/lawvere metric spaces. With the group definition, you are saying what transformations are permissible, but not what the implied structure is (explicitly, anyway).

I've seen authors use concepts equivalence classes and total orders when discussing scales, e.g. Michell (1986), Suppes & Zines (1962), I just haven't been able to find something similar for ratio scales.

The original paper by Stevens was couched in the language of group theory: the structure is that of the action of a group on the numbers used to represent the data.  The groups in ratio and interval scales are identical but the actions differ slightly (additive vs. multiplicative).
